# A lower bound when the recurrence is based on primes

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, recurrence-relations

I have a recurrence of the form $w(n) \geq p_n\cdot(w(n-1) - 1)$, where $p_n$ is the largest prime less than or equal to $n$.  If $w(1) = a$ for some $a > 10$, how good of a lower bound on $w(n)$ can one obtain?

Bertrand's postulate says that $p > n/2$, and I know there are generalizations of his postulate that give better bounds...

Comment: Your question is not well-defined. We want to start with $n=1$, but we cannot! Indeed, "$p_n$ is the largest prime less than or equal to $n$"; but then what is $p_1$? There are no primes less than or equal to 1!

Comment: Note that usually $p_n$ denotes the $n$th prime.

Comment: @Alex Perhaps I'm misunderstanding you, but I stated that $w(1) = a > 10$.  Then $w(2) \geq p_2 (a-1)$, where $p_2 = 2$.  We never need $p_1$, and all other $p_i$ are large.

Comment: Thanks, the question looks good then! Except I'd prefer to see $w(n)=\ldots$ rather than $w(n)\ge\ldots$

Comment: @Alex  Indeed, perhaps I should have named it something else.  What I mean though I as I defined it.

Comment: As a conjectural lower bound for $p_n$ you can use $p_n>n-\log^2n$. This is based on a modified form of Cramer's conjecture.

Comment: Ok thank you!  I will more about that